# Files needed to port opencv

Tags: file, opencv, port

If I were to port opencv to another language, would I only need to port the files in the include folder of the dist, or would I need to port everything except the examples.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes, you will need to port everything.  Porting the headers will only get you as far as compiling (not linking) your code against the ported headers.
Porting the examples is up to you, but if you don't do it, how will you know everything is working?

Longer answer: what language are you porting to?  If it's Python, there is no need, as there is already a Python interface.  Do you need to port at all?  Can you get away with just writing wrappers for your language using something like [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/)?  A full port is almost always the worst case scenario -- try and avoid it.  If you include a bit more detail in your question (why you're doing it, what the environment is, etc) then you may get some alternatives as advice.

Comment: Well, I was originally going to use swig to "port" opencv to go.  I was hoping to use some of the basic features of opencv.